# Canvas ID cropped to a predefined size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i'm currently working on a js project.

I'm drawing some canvas but something is wrong with the code i have:

```
<div id="canvasesdiv" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: table-cell; position: relative; width:578px; height:415.5px">  
    <canvas id="c1"      style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; left: 80px; width="680" height="435"></canvas>   
    <canvas id="c2"      style="z-index: 2; position:absolute; left: 80px; width="680" height="435"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c3"      style="z-index: 3; position:absolute; left: 80px; width="680" height="435"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c4"      style="z-index: 4; position:absolute; left: 80px; width="680" height="435"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c5"      style="z-index: 5; position:absolute; left: 80px; width="680" height="435"></canvas>
</div>
```

Cleary width and height are parsed wrongly (html is expecting : and the values in px) but somehow the canvases are drawn in their full dimension.
Instead if i use something like:

```
<canvas id="c1"     style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; left: 80px; "></canvas>   
<canvas id="c2"     style="z-index: 2; position:absolute; left: 80px; "></canvas>
<canvas id="c3"     style="z-index: 3; position:absolute; left: 80px; "></canvas>
<canvas id="c4"     style="z-index: 4; position:absolute; left: 80px; "></canvas>
<canvas id="c5"     style="z-index: 5; position:absolute; left: 80px; "></canvas>
```

or with

```
... width: 500px; height: 500px;"
```

The canvases are all cropped down to 300x150 no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set value of canvas in pixels. You can place canvas into div than in load event and resize event you can calculate real size of parent div than set his values into canvas. You can use JQuery for that.

Comment: the problem seems related to "position:absolute". If i remove that attribuite, the canvases respect the dimension but i lose the overlay feature. How can i solve it? @Ivan Mjartan

Comment: Basically the size 300x150 is the default one for Firefox.
See here http://jsfiddle.net/ecTCD/87/ and here http://jsfiddle.net/ecTCD/91/ the difference with position:absolute.
Any idea?

Comment: My suggestion is let it be absolute and in the event just change size. When you do that all drawing disappear. So after resize you have to redraw everything. To optimize resize action use just semaphore (bool value is resize) and timer with delay 100ms or more. Every resize event just reset your time and draw thing when user finish resizing.  If you have lots of thinks to draw it is better approach to create off-screen canvas first draw into it than onresize event draw off-screen canvas to visible one.

Comment: See this example, can you fix it so that the position is absolute but the size is whatever you want and centered?

http://jsfiddle.net/ecTCD/96/

If i add position:absolute, the overlay works but it is out of the div bound, see here

http://jsfiddle.net/ecTCD/98/